# Constructing Orbits of the Automorphism of a Graph Group in Bliss

Tags: graph-isomorphism, software

I'm using the [Bliss](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/) package for graph isomorphism and canonization. The program is working great for the type of graphs I'm interested in. In one of the applications I need to compute the orbits of the automorphism group of the graph. What is the best way to do that in Bliss?

PS: I understand that some people may think that this question is off-topic because it asks about a specific software. But since bliss is a highly specialized software that is used mostly by TCS people (at least consciously) I think that this site is the best one to ask this question. I also think that this may be useful for other researchers interested in graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If Bliss is not mandatory, you can try Sage: https://www.sagemath.org/
I used it successfully a few times.

This video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4_4Bqj6EdA&t=579s
Gives a usage example.